# How to remove timezone abbreviation in js?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I have code:

```
var date = '2014/01/01';
date = new Date(Date.parse(date));
date = date.toString();
```

I get string like this - "Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (MSK)". It's good, but in my case i need to get string without "(MSK)"

I need - "Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0400" only!

How can i do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a string, just do something like:

`date = date.toString();
date = date.replace(/\([A-Z]+\)$/,"");`

You could also change the format by passing in a new value to **date.toString("%format%")**, as per:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

..but for what you need, simply doing the replacement would be the easiest :)

Comment: No problem :) If you would be so kind as to mark my answer as the correct one (by pressing the "tick" image, that would be great.

Comment: Hm, one more, what if there would be: "Mon Apr 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Московское время (зима))"?

Comment: If its non-latin you also want to match, then this should do it: `date = date.replace(/\(.+?\)$/,"");`